# Replace one row with many changing a column value based on an object

Tags: r, dataframe

I've tried to find the answer to this simple question without anyluck.

Let's say I have:

```
A <- c(1101,1102,1103)
```

and a dataframe that looks like this:

```
t    m    com   x
1    1    1101  10
1    1    1102  15
1    1    1103  20
1    2    NA    NA
1    3    1101  20
1    3    1102  25
1    3    1103  30
1    4    NA    NA
1    5    1101  25
1    5    1102  30
1    5    1103  35
```

and since what I want to do is a linear interpolation of X with na.approx (actual dataframe and object are way bigger), I need the dataframe to look like this:

```
t    m    com   x
1    1    1101  10
1    1    1102  15
1    1    1103  20
1    2    1101  NA
1    2    1102  NA
1    2    1103  NA
1    3    1101  20
1    3    1102  25
1    3    1103  30
1    4    1101  NA
1    4    1102  NA
1    4    1103  NA
1    5    1101  25
1    5    1102  30
1    5    1103  35
```

I haven't tried any code for this because I don't know where to start.

Any help and/or r material that you consider usefull would be great.

Thanks,

Comment: You need to say more about what you want to do. What is the relevance of `A`? What to `t`, `m`, and `com` have to do with anything? You say you want to do linear interpolation of `X`, so why are there still `NA` values in `X` in the desired result? You say the question is simple - please state it simply.

Comment: "A" contains all the values of com, it's the object I need to use to use. The columns t and m are there to properly reflect on the need to go from one row to many.  I already know the linear interpolation part, I just need to transform the dataframe rows to be able to execute the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you need is `tidyr::complete()`.

1. Since you would like to "expand" column `com` within group of `m`, you need to `group_by(m)` first,
2. then use the vector `A` to `complete` the `com` column.
3. In this case, the `t` column will be filled with `NA` by default, we can `fill()` up column `t` using the value in the previous row (since you said you have a large dataset, this should work better than setting the `fill` parameter in `complete()`).
4. Then drop any `NA` in the `com` column (these are the original `NA` in your data set).
5. Finally, reorder the columns back to their original position.

```
library(tidyverse)

A <- c(1101,1102,1103)

df %>% 
  group_by(m) %>% 
  complete(com = A) %>% 
  fill(t, .direction = "up") %>% 
  drop_na(com) %>% 
  select(t, m, com, x)

# A tibble: 15 x 4
# Groups:   m [5]
       t     m   com     x
   <int> <int> <dbl> <int>
 1     1     1  1101    10
 2     1     1  1102    15
 3     1     1  1103    20
 4     1     2  1101    NA
 5     1     2  1102    NA
 6     1     2  1103    NA
 7     1     3  1101    20
 8     1     3  1102    25
 9     1     3  1103    30
10     1     4  1101    NA
11     1     4  1102    NA
12     1     4  1103    NA
13     1     5  1101    25
14     1     5  1102    30
15     1     5  1103    35
```

Comment: Thank you very much, great explanation of the solution and Complete is a useful tool to have in the repertoir.